# data is not updating in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Hi im using jquery datatable(https://datatables.net/). im adding some values in database and refreshing the datatable but datatable is showing old values. once i refresh the browser then it is showing updated value. can anyone help on this issue?

```
     function display_comments(){
       $.ajax({
        url: getcomments_URL,
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data, status, xhr) {

                $.each(circuitPremisesJson, function(index, item) {

                    var option = "<tr><td>" + item.comments + "</td><td>" + item.comment_TYPE + "</td><td>" + item.lname + "</td><td>" + item.action_PERFORMED + "</td><td>" + item.entry_TIME + "</td></tr>";

                    $('#div_comment_list tbody').append(option);
                });
                $('#div_comment_list').DataTable({destroy: true});                  

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(ajaxOptions);
        }
    });
    }

    $("#add_comments").click(function(){
    // here i have ajax code for add comments in database


    display_comments();  / refreshing the datatable 

    });
```

Comment: is this a typo: `display_comments();  / refreshing the datatable` with the comment?

Comment: display_comments() method contain the  ajax call for fetch and display the comments in datatable. after adding the comment in db im calling display_comments() method

Comment: Ok, I assumed in my answer it was a syntax error and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

**Errors and changes:**

- You have one unknown here: `getcomments_URL` I guess that is some global variable somewhere?
- `circuitPremisesJson` was not in your code, I assume it is the data returned, this replaced that with `data`
- Invalid comment added second / `display_comments(); / refreshing the datatable` in that line
- you can use the `success` and `error` but I find the `.done` and `.fail` looks cleaner to me.
- multiple `$('#div_comment_list')` so I cached that selector in `c`
- I did not like `option` as a name for a table row string so I changed it
- `var newTableRow ="";` creation of variables in a loop is not optimal so I added this line

**Code**

```
function display_comments() {
  $.ajax({
    url: getcomments_URL,
    method: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
    var c = $('#div_comment_list');
    var newTableRow ="";
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      newTableRow = "<tr><td>" + item.comments + "</td><td>" + item.comment_TYPE + "</td><td>" + item.lname + "</td><td>" + item.action_PERFORMED + "</td><td>" + item.entry_TIME + "</td></tr>";
      c.find('tbody').append(newTableRow);
    });
    c.DataTable({
      destroy: true
    });
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
  });
}

$("#add_comments").click(function() {
  // here i have ajax code for add comments in database
  display_comments(); // refreshing the datatable
});
```

**EDIT: Update Datatable portion**

Just to concentrate on the Datatable update portion, I created a new fiddle.  That whole thing is here:

Here are the key portions of that.  I like to use namespaces for my Javascript when it gets complex so let's do that:

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
```

Then add an object called "commentTable" to hold our Datatable:

```
myApp.components = {
  commentTable: {},
  ... more components
```

These are the key rows: (see how I useed the namespace `myApp.components.commentTable`)

```
myApp.components.commentTable.row.add(commentRow);
myApp.components.commentTable.draw();
```

That first line adds rows to our new Datatable object.  The second redraws the table with the new data. That adds the row directly to the table, you could do that and be done.

Here is my code above reworked for that:

```
.done(function(data, status, xhr) {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
          var commentRow = {
              "comments": item.comments,
              "comment_TYPE": item.comment_TYPE,
              "lname": item.lname,
              "action_PERFORMED": item.action_PERFORMED,
              "entry_TIME": item.entry_TIME
        }
        myApp.components.commentTable.row.add(commentRow);
      });
      myApp.components.commentTable.draw();
    })
```

The key to that above is my declaration of the comment rows objects in my namespaced data here:

```
myApp.data = {
  commentsURL: "https://www.example.com/comments/get",
  commentcolumns: [{
    title: 'Comments',
    data: 'comments'
  }, {
    title: 'Type',
    data: 'comment_TYPE'
  }, {
    title: 'Last Name',
    data: 'lname'
  }, {
    title: 'Action',
    data: 'action_PERFORMED'
  }, {
    title: 'Time',
    data: 'entry_TIME'
  }],
  commentdata: [{
    "comments": "Caught some fish in the lake.",
    "comment_TYPE": "Fisherman",
    "lname": "Wonka",
    "action_PERFORMED": "caught",
    "entry_TIME": new Date(2016, 4, 21, 18, 45, 23, 9)
  },...more rows
  ],
  ...more data stuff
};
```

Here is where/how I declared the Datatable using my namespace:

```
myApp.components.commentTable = $('#exampleemtpy').DataTable({
  data: myApp.data.columndata,
  columns: myApp.data.commentcolumns
});
```

Markup for the table (all of it)

OR it could be populated with data as my second table is in the fiddle.

See this all in action here: (Note this has a bit more as I wanted to actually test adding rows, SO, I added a form and manual methods to insert since I did NOT have any ajax server; ignore that all and focus on the lines noted above)

Fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/gwawccqt/4/

Comment: i done all changes u mentioned here. even the datatable displaying old values only. once i refesh the browser than only it is showing updated values

Comment: I added some details for the Datatable portion as you seem to have a challenge there also. Note that I used the newer DataTable not the older dataTable, that confuses SO many people, search the differences...

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link on how to Reload the datatable data from the Ajax data source.
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: im using my own ajax call, im not using Datatable ajax